# Null Object Reference When Trying to Display EditText Value in TextView - Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I know this question has been asked a few times, but I have tried the solutions and the error is still coming up in the debugger.

I have a small form which has a pet name, which type of animal the pet is, and what breed. I have two spinners in which the second is based on the first value, and then I have a switch case which takes the user to the correct breed page when they press go.

Basically I wanted to add to my switch case a `setText` which would say something like 'Now showing tailored information for *Pet Name*', however when I run on the debugger it throws a `null object reference error`.

I had a few `textViews` with the same id so I changed it to a unique `id` and that never made any difference.. Any help is appreciated.

Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.petsopedia, PID: 15588
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.petsopedia.Questionnaire$3$1.onClick(Questionnaire.java:117)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

XML

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/petName"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textfield_width"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autofillHints="@string/pet_name"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:hint="@string/pet_name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:labelFor="@string/pet_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.65" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/breed_spinner"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textfield_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:labelFor="@id/breed_spinner"
    android:text="@string/pet_breed"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.804" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/which_spinner"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textfield_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/spinner_height"
    android:fontFamily="serif"
    android:labelFor="@id/which_spinner"
    android:text="@string/pet_type"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.735" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="216dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.9">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/maleRadio"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="@string/male" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femaleRadio"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/female" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/goQuestionnaire"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons"
    android:text="@string/go_button"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />
```

TextView on the target page

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txResultAlsatian"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Java

```
       EditText petName  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.petName);
        TextView alsatianResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResultAlsatian);

     breedSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                switch (breedSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
                    case "Alsatian":
                        goButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v)
                            {
                                String value = petName.getText().toString();
                                //result.setText("Name:" + txValue );
                                alsatianResult.setText(value);
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Questionnaire.this, PetInfoAlsatian.class);

                                startActivity(intent);



                            }
                        });
                        break;
         }
            }
```

Comment: Can you try to move `TextView alsatianResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txResultAlsatian);`  inside the listener callback just before `alsatianResult.setText(value);`

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: you shared a layout that has the EditText `petName`, but the TextView `txResultAlsatian` is not in it .. does it exist in another layout file?

Comment: Yes the `txResultAlsatian` is in another page, which is where the go button takes the user

Comment: You must have the `txResultAlsatian` in the same layout that you set in `setContentView()` .. otherwise it will raise NullPointerException

Comment: Oh okay.. thats a shame.. Maybe I can try and display it in a toast before the user goes to the page..

Comment: Toast worked great!